# What is the working of web Crawler?

Tags: php, python

Will web crawler crawl the web and create a database of the web or it will just create a searchable index of web? If suppose it creates an index, who will exactly will gather the data of web pages and store it in database?

Comment: how much web would a web crawler crawl if a web crawler could crawl web

Comment: Your question doesn't mention which web crawler you are talking about.  Therefore it's too vague for stackoverflow.

Comment: What does this question have to do with PHP or Python?  Do you want to write one?  Is there an existing one that you're trying to hack?

Comment: Actually I have to implement a crawler and I don't know anything about it . I have to learn Python for it.

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is slightly vague Let me puts some words to clarify.

1. Crawler makes http request of a URL and analyse the information of that web page. Say for example it makes a http req. http://www.example.com it retrieves the content of the page.
2. Once it gets the content of the page it analyse it. Now comes the importance of H1, H2 , P tages base on these tags it gets a clue of what the web page is all about.
3. Identifies the important/prominent words called keywords and summarise the page content and puts it in its index
4. Also it gets hyperlinks to other websites from that page that will be used in its next jump to those website and it proceeds further. It is a never ending story.
5. So whenever a keyword is being asked it looks from the keyword database and it shows in the result.
6. Sometimes the crawler itself dumps the copy of the web pages in a special database called cache database so that it can be used as alternate copy of the original data.

Comment: 1.In point 3, you have mentioned summarising the page content and puts in its index. How is the relation between the keywords and the page is maintained?
2.How do we know that particular keyword is from that page only. How is it actually implemented?
3. What exactly is contained in index?

Comment: Keywords, and other meta tags can be mapped to URL, Also all the urls originating from the site can be grouped under one entity called the domain name,